# what is the MOST smallest OS that can be installed on a windows tablet(uefi)

Tags: operating-system, touchscreen

My tablet supports booting from FAT32 usb drives. And maybe ntfs is also supported.
I want an OS that would be the lightest, smallest, use minimum of both disk space and RAM.
It has to have support for touchscreen input + on-screen-keyboard. Otherwise it's inconvenient to carry usb hub + keyboard + mouse.
Would be nice to have a way to recover this OS(recovery partition, file), just like on Windows 8/10, in case something goes wrong...with my fingers and me ;)

I need this OS for mostly browsing the web(reading news, mail, youtube videos in 720p, listening to music, using web forums). And a simple GUI just like on Windows, Mac OS X or Ubuntu.

I could install Android, but to me it's not true desktop OS yet.